# run Rmpi on cluster, specify library path

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I'm trying to run an analysis in parallel on our computing cluster.
Unfortunately I've had to set up Rmpi myself and may not have done so properly.
Because I had to install all necessary packages into my home folder, I always have to call

```
.libPaths('/home/myfolder/Rlib');
```

before I can load packages.

However, it appears that `doMPI` attempts to load itself, before I can set the library path.

```
.libPaths('/home/myfolder/Rlib');
cat("Step 1")
library(doMPI)
cl <- startMPIcluster()
registerDoMPI(cl)
cat("Step 2")
Children_mcmc1 = foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% {
    cat("Step 3")
    .libPaths('/home/myfolder/Rlib');
    library(MCMCglmm)
    cat("Step 4")
    load("krmh_married.rdata")
    nitt = 1000; thin = 50; burnin = 100
    MCMCglmm( children ~ paternalage.factor ,
        random=~idParents,
        family="poisson", 
        data=krmh_married, 
        pr = F, saveX = T, saveZ = T,
        nitt=nitt,thin=thin,burnin=burnin)
}
closeCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

If I do

```
mpirun -H localhost -n 3 R --slave -f "3 - krmh mcmcglmm scc test 2.r"
```

I get (after removing some boilerplate messages)

> During startup - Warning message:
>   Step 1
>   Step 1
>   Step 1
>   Step 2Error in { : task 2 failed - "cannot open the connection"
>   Calls: %dopar% -> 
>   Execution halted

If I do

```
R --slave -f "3 - krmh mcmcglmm scc test 2.r"
```

I get

> Step 1
>   Error in library(doMPI) : there is no package called 'doMPI'
>   Calls: local ... eval -> suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> library
>   Execution halted
>   Error in library(doMPI) : there is no package called 'doMPI'
>   Calls: local ... eval -> suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> library
>   Execution halted

I've tried installing `doMPI` on the run, but even though Step 2 isn't printed, it seems as if the error results from the loop.

And of course, with all this I'm still testing on our frontend, I haven't it made it to submitting the job to the intended cluster yet.

I tried to specify the `.libPaths` call in my .Rprofile, but I'm not sure this would get read on the cluster and I can't even get it to get read on the frontend (and I couldn't figure out where R is looking for the file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to install R packages into a "personal library", since it is used automatically so you don't have to call `.libPaths` in your scripts. You can determine what directory this is by executing:

```
> Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER')
```

This will automatically be the first directory returned by `.libPaths` if it exists, so you don't have to worry about calling `.libPaths` at all.

Note that there's no point in calling `.libPaths` in the body of the foreach loop since doMPI must be loaded by the cluster workers before they can execute any tasks.

I'm not sure what's going wrong in your "mpirun" case, because mpirun is starting all of the workers, so the first four lines of your script are executed by all of them. That is why "Step 1" is displayed three times. But in your second case, the cluster workers are being spawned, so the doMPI package is loaded by the RMPIworker.R script, resulting in the error loading doMPI.

I suggest that you use the mpirun approach to solve the `.libPaths` problem, but call `startMPIcluster` with the `verbose=TRUE` option. That will create some files in your working directory named "MPI_*.log" which may contain some useful error messages that will provide a clue to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your excellent packages! For some reason I thought I didn't have a personal library because the directory referenced in `R_LIBS_USER` had to be created. This makes things a lot easier. I do get a step further (to "cannot open the connection" with the `R --slave` way. I'll try more during the week. The "connection" problem may be due to the attempt to load the data file, maybe I need to give a full path or something like that?

Comment: @Ruben "cannot open the connection" is the error produced by the load command if it can't find the file, so specifying the full path would be a useful test.

Comment: It was indeed an iffy path causing that error. But now I verified that the code inside the foreach works on it own, and I get `Error: ReadItem: unknown type 0, perhaps written by later version of R` with both methods (3 times with mpirun).

Comment: @Ruben It sounds like mpirun is using the wrong version of R, possibly due to your shell init scripts. Try specifying the full path to R when executing mpirun.

Comment: It sounds like it, but `mpirun -H localhost -n 3 R --version` yields Spring Dance and either way that problem shouldn't occur with the `R --slave` method, right? Any other ideas?

Comment: This wasn't the problem, maybe again something with the path... I don't know why specifying the full file path for the file and executing mpirun from my home dir instead of my proj dir solved it, but it did. For the mpirun method to work, I also had to add `closeCluster(cl); mpi.quit()` to the end of the script (edited my question to add).